# The shrink and his patient (Part 2)

Tags: riddle, story, visual

<sub>If you missed the first part, [here it is](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42631/the-shrink-and-his-patient-part-1).</sub>

---

Harold reached home the faster he could. Quick, to the baby's bed. "No, no, no, it can be true!". He searched the whole house but he could not find the baby or his wife.
Instead, in Anne's bed, he found a piece of paper similar to the one in his office. This time, the text was different:

> Do not worry, Mr. Smith : your wife and your baby are safe. Eventually,
>   you will meet them again, but first, let me tell you a little story.
>   Remember that we both enjoy puzzles, and I am counting on you for this
>   one too!
>
> A long time ago, a famous group of seven men was created, but I can't
>   remember the name of this group or the name of its folks.
>
> Three of these men didn't have a particular backstory, all I can say is that they were from India. Also, one of them joined the group later. Maybe the flag will help you, shrink:

[image]

> Two of them were brothers. They were often mixed up, and some people
>   are still not sure if the older one really was a part of the group (he also
>   joined later). The younger one was known as extravagant and a bit
>   individualist. It's funny, because their names, though different, had
>   the same origin.
>
> One of them liked to disclose his identity like this:
>
> ```
> Some see me spontaneous or jealous
> But others find me happy and glorious
> Of course, glorious! I'm associated with gold
> And like my comrades, I'm certainly old
> They even made a video game
> Popular enough to wear my name
> You might struggle to guess who my mates are
> But for me, it's simple: I'm like a star!
> ```
>
> You think I forgot to talk about the last one? I don't think so, Mr. Smith. You need to read carefully, as always.
>
> So, Mr. Smith, can you find the name of the members, and the name of the group? If you do so, then find me at the eponymous restaurant.
>   Your wife and your baby are waiting for you.

"God dammit, another puzzle", thought Harold. He was relieved to know that Sandra and Anne were safe, even if he wasn't sure if he could trust this piece of paper.
He tried to remember all the names of the restaurants in town, but there were too many. "I'd better solve it fast", he said.
He got the first six members easily, but the last one was tricky. Finding the name of the group was easy once he got all of them. After he solved it, he promptly left to the indicated place.

**What is the name of the restaurant where Harold is going?**

Comment: The first ["famous group of seven men"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Seven_Dwarfs_(1937_film)) that came to my mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The seven men are

> Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, and Violet.

The first three (that come from India) are

> Orange, Green, and Blue. These are the three colors shown in the flag. Also, orange was "added" to the rainbow late (Newton's original spectrum did not include orange and indigo).

The two brothers are

> Indigo and violet. These colors are tougher to distinguish, and people may get them mixed up. Indigo was added to the spectrum later (mentioned above). Their names both come from flowers (see [here for indigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo) and [here for violet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_(color))).

The man in the poem is

> Yellow. [Yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow) is often associated with jealousy, and is the color of gold. Pokemon Yellow was a popular video game. Stars are often considered yellow.

The last man is

> Red. Take the letters of the first paragraph of the note, and you get the letters D (*Don't*), E (*Eventually*) and R (*Remember*).

The group is

> the Rainbow

and the restaurant is

> The Rainbow Room at 30 Rock (part 1 referenced that he was in Manhattan.)

Comment: Well, you got almost everything! The red color is hidden somewhere else though. Also, if you could explain the riddle a bit more, I'll be pleased!

Answer (score 11):

I think the seven men are

> the colours of the rainbow,

so Mr Smith should go to

> the Rainbow Cafe.

---

I worked this out from the fact that you'd not only said three of them are from India, but also included a picture of the Indian flag, which doesn't *seem* to add any additional information.

> The three colours (excluding white) which appear on the Indian flag are **green**, **orange**, and a deep navy blue which could be interpreted as either blue or indigo. <strike>I'm going to take it as **indigo**, since the very word "indigo" [is cognate with "India"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indigo#Etymology).</strike> Never mind, the OP [says](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32622464#32622464) it's **blue**. (Orange is the "one [who] joined the group later", since it wasn't originally on the list of colours of the rainbow.)

*Two of them were brothers. They were often mixed up, and some people are still not sure if he really was a part of the group (he also joined later). The younger one was know as extravagant and a bit individualist. It's funny, because their names, though different, had the same origin.*

> The "brothers" are likely to be indigo and violet. The one who "joined later" is **indigo**, since Newton's original list of colours of the rainbow included only red, yellow, green, blue, and violet, and "some people" (such as Isaac Asimov) have expressed doubt as to whether it should be included on the list at all. **Violet**, meanwhile, is seen as an extravagant and perhaps individualist colour. I'm not sure about the "names [having] the same origin" though.

*Some see me spontaneous or jealous

But others find me happy and glorious

Of course, glorious! I'm associated with gold

And like my comrades, I'm certainly old

They even made a video game

Popular enough to wear my name

You might struggle to guess who my mates are

But for me, it's simple: I'm like a star!*

> I'm going to say this refers to **yellow**, being "associated with gold" and also "like a star" (stars in pictures are often shown as being yellow). Yellow [is associated with](http://www.empower-yourself-with-color-psychology.com/personality-color-yellow.html) spontaneity and happiness, [as well as](http://www.color-wheel-pro.com/color-meaning.html) jealousy, and there is [a video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Yellow) called Pokemon Yellow.

*You think I forgot to talk about the last one? I don't think so, Mr. Smith. You need to read carefully, as always.*

> This must be **red**, but I can't find it mentioned anywhere else within the puzzle. The best idea I can come up with is to take the first letter of every paragraph, which gives DATTOYS. Sounds vaguely meaningful, but I can't see the connection to red. The OP [has confirmed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32622773#32622773) that I'm on the right track with this.

Comment: For the last clue, maybe look at the opposite of what you already tried, and only for the highlighted part.